# unwrap with thickness with complicated objects

Tags: uv

Is there a way to unwrap a object but not only the surface but also add a thickness that matches when folding together
for simple forms it would be no problem but with angled surfaces its not so easy

I am pretty new and i tried two different ways:

1. with extruding the edges inwards , solidifiy them ,then boolean diff but it is very messy and not laid flat
2. with uv maps from a outer and inner surface but I dont know if that is possible somehow

unfold like this:
[image: unfold like this]
with a complex object like this:

[image: with a complicated object like this]

Your ideas are appreciated.